# Cycle through certain range in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, cycle

I have this code

```
int x = 0
int MAX = 21;
int MIN = 18;
char *arr[40];
do{
  char* current = cycle(x,arr)
  x++;
}while(x<10000000)
```

My cycle() currently cycles through entire array

```
unsigned char *cycle(int counter, unsigned char *packets[40]){
int tmp = counter % 40;
return packets[tmp];
 }
```

But I want it to cycle in array just in [MIN,MAX] range.
So the return values in while loop are: arr[18], arr[19], arr[20], arr[21], arr[18], arr[19]...

Any idea how to implement this? I don't want solutions using global variable.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Add a new function, `cycle_range` which takes the min/max limits as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sometype cycle_range(int counter, sometype array[], unsigned min, unsigned max) {

    sometype* first = array+min;
    unsigned length = max-min+1;

    return first[counter % length];
}
```

This works just like your solution, but it starts `min` elements further in `array` and loops over `max-min+1` elements instead of `40`.

(`sometype` is `unsigned char*` in your case, but you can substitute another type here if you want)

Comment: Why the declaration, assignment and use of `first`? Why not just do: `return array[min + (counter % (max - min + 1));`

Comment: That's exactly the same thing, just looks better if you break it down

Comment: agreed; when maintaining code, I'd much rather see the broken-down version than `array[min + (counter % (max - min + 1))]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char *cycle(int counter,int min, int max, unsigned char *packets[40]){
    int tmp = (counter % (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return packets[tmp];
}
```